# HP X1400 HDD Upgrade from 4 to 8 TB

Tags: hp, hard-drive

i have an HP X1400 Storage Server with 4x 1TB HDD´s. Now i replace them with 4x 2TB HDD´s
but the system shows only 4TB, can anybody help me?
Sorry, i´m the first time here....
It was an HP AP786B X1400,  it comes with Windows Storage Server 2008 Standard and 4x 500 GB SATA 7.2k LFF MDL HDDs. I removed them and put
4x HP 507632-B21  2TB SATA 7.2k LFF Hot-Plug into the machine. Than I made an recovery from
the recovery DVD but after that the system shows only 4x 500 GB instead of 4x 2TB....
Thanks for your help and sorry for my english

Comment: How did you replace them? what exact method

Comment: You didn't give any information on how you did the upgrade, what the partitioning is showing, if it is using RAID,...?

Comment: You should read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

It's a software RAID, I believe, based on the [HP Quickspecs](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13839_div/13839_div.html). Can you see the additional hard drive space in the Windows Disk Management MMC?

Comment: No i can.t ´see it, it shows 4x 500GB